# Laser Retro value not returned by the RaySensor sensor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,
I am setting the laser_retro value in the link of my model as following:

```
<collision name="basic_square_garden_collision">
<laser_retro>2000.0</laser_retro>
....
```

And then reading it out as following:

```
this->parent_ray_sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetRetro(ja)
this->parent_ray_sensor_ is cast to RaySensor.
```

Now the problem is that the laser_retro value does not seem to be set and is then also not read. The latter I verified with the following command:

```
gztopic echo  /gazebo/default/lawnmower/base_footprint/lawnsensor/scan
```

Does anyone have an example for setting and reading out this value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2369/laser-retro-value-not-returned-by-the-raysensor-sensor/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Setting up the return as follows worked for me but not sure if this is the right way:

```
diff -r 5ebae74ef4ea -r b1e29966c852 gazebo/physics/Collision.cc
--- a/gazebo/physics/Collision.cc   Thu Apr 04 16:55:58 2013 -0700
+++ b/gazebo/physics/Collision.cc   Fri Apr 12 21:27:45 2013 -0700
@@ -83,6 +83,13 @@
 {
   Entity::Load(_sdf);

+  float retro;
+  if (this->sdf->HasElement("laser_retro"))
+    {
+      retro = this->sdf->GetElement("laser_retro")->GetValueDouble();
+      this->SetLaserRetro(retro);
+    }
+
```

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) with karma: 60 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-04-24**:
I believe this has been merged into Gazebo default, and will come out in Gazebo 1.8.0